# C# Const field in abstract class

Tags: c#, constants, abstract

I'm having trouble declaring a const field in an abstract class. Why is this?

#### edit

I should have clarified. My problem is that my child classes can't see the const field:

```
protected const string Prefix = "dynfrm_";
```

If I remove the const keyword, I can get to it from a grandchild class.

Comment: Given which answer directed you to the solution, you should have shown quite a bit more code. If we had actually seen your code, it would have been clear.

Comment: That's why I asked for the error message :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As long as you initialize it in the declaration, there shouldn't be an issue. What is the error message you are receiving?

Comment: Error message? That's brilliant! "cannot be accessed with an instance reference; qualify it with a type name instead." I did this and it works. I guess it treats it as static when you use the const keyword.

Comment: I was trying to access using this.Field.

Answer (score 4):

```
public abstract class Class1
{
    protected const string Prefix = "dynfrm_";
}

public class Class2 : Class1
{
    public void GetConst()
    {
        Console.WriteLine(Prefix);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Here you go...

```
abstract class MyBase
{
    protected const int X = 10;
}
class Derived : MyBase
{
    Derived()
    {
        Console.WriteLine(MyBase.X);
    }
}
```

Comment: MyBase is just base in c#. Besides, base.myConstFiled isn't working for me.

Comment: base is a c# keyword for the base class of the current class. MyBase is what Gishu declared as the abstract class in his sample code.

Answer (score 2):

Seems to work fine:

```
public abstract class Class1
{
    protected const int Field1 = 1;
}

public class Class2 : Class1
{
    public int M1()
    {
        return Field1;
    }
}
```

I'm using Visual Studio 2008 SP1, and I see the protected const in IntelliSense from a descendant and it compiles as expected.

Answer (score 1):

Did you make your constant at least protected? if it's private it won't be accessible by child classes just as it wouldn't if it wasn't an abstract class.

Edit: I see you posted an example - and did specify it as protected, which works for me.  Got a description of what happens? Doesn't compile? run time error?

Comment: If a class is defined as abstact then it can never be initialized. Wouldn't this stop the compiler from initializing a const, which is inherently static?